# Karaf With Hibernate-Enver Not Working

Tags: hibernate, apache-karaf, hibernate-envers

I am trying to audit my entities (using -`hibernate-envers`)so i am using `Hibernate-5.10.2-Final` with `apache-Karaf-4.0.7`.. The issue is that when i run as Java Application . audit tables of entites are created with REVINFO and enteries are made in aud table to each save/update  ..But When Deployed to karaf, _AUD tables are created succesfully but no record insert to audit table on save/update ..

Can anyOne please help me out to solve this?

Comment: That sounds particularly like the event listeners aren't firing for some reason.  Its obvious that Envers is being detected.  Can you enable debug logging and provide some relevent information for what you see occurring?

Comment: when i add following properties in persistance.xml
`hibernate.integration.envers.enabled = true`
`hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=true`
I got exception :
`org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistrationException: Duplicate event listener found
 at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.listenerShouldGetAdded(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:126)
 at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.appendListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:91)
`
for hibernate 4 + no need to handle envers-listeners

Comment: Correct, as long as the jar is found, you don't need to add those those configurations anymore, it happens automatically.

Comment: @Naros can you help me why I am getting the above exception?

Comment: @Naros you got it right , i need to registers the event listeners in my application. by doing so , its working !!!